# Ionic-4 ion-alert-controller create function not working

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic with vanila java script
I am using CDN in head component

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>
```

In the body of HTML

```
<ion-alert-controller></ion-alert-controller>
......
.....
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

in app.js

```
const alertCtrl = document.querySelector('ion-alert-controller');
..
..
..
alertCtrl.create ({
                message: 'ABC',
                header: 'DEF',
                button: ['Okay']
            });
```

getting an error saying

app.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: alertCtrl.create is not a function
at HTMLElement. (app.js:29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not used to code with vanilla, but according to Ionic docs for js, you should use alertController this way :

```
const alertCtrl = document.querySelector('ion-alert-controller');
alertCtrl.message ='ABC';
alertCtrl.header='DEF';
alertCtrl.button= ['OK'];
```

Comment: Thanks for this , I was kind of mixing up <ion-alert-controller> and <ion-alert> as per wrongly following a guide :) This worked fine .

Comment: Happy to help.Don't forget to vote for my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation.
The ionic CDN you are using will download the latest version of ionic, however I guess `ion-alert-controller` directive is ionic 4.

you need to use

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.2/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.2/dist/ionic.js"></script>
```

Note that the links above refer to `unpkg.com`, not `jsdelivr.net`

Please refer to

```
https://unpkg.com/browse/@ionic/core@4.1.0-dev.201902272232.d66b12b/README.md
```

lines 26 & 27